# Como hacer para recargar ventanas modales en Django?

Tags: python, django

Lo que quiero hacer es que si el mensaje se activa , el JS lo tomo y entonces vuelva abrir el modal con el formulario y el error, solo es eso.

Pero no se como hacerlo.

Esta es la vista:

```
def inventarioingresoe(request):
    #Codigo para calcular fecha actual
    fecha = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    #Codigo para calcular hora actual
    hora = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if request.method == "POST":
        variedad = request.POST["variedad"]
        empaque = request.POST["empaque"]
        grado = request.POST["grado"]
        comercializadora = request.POST["comercializadora"]
        ramos = request.POST["ramos"]
        unidades = request.POST["unidades"]
        celda = request.POST["celda"]

        if Empaque.objects.filter(celda=celda):
            mensaje = 'La celda ya esta ocupada'
            return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {'mensaje' : mensaje})
        else:
            nuevoingreso = Empaque.objects.create( fecha = fecha,
                                                   hora = hora,
                                                   variedad = variedad,
                                                   empaque = empaque,
                                                   grado = grado,
                                                   comercializadora = comercializadora,
                                                   ramos = ramos,
                                                   unidades = unidades,
                                                   celda = celda)
            return redirect('empaque')

    return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {})
```

Esta es la url:

```
url(r'^inventario/ingreso/$', SGregorio_views.inventarioingresoe, name='empaqueingreso'),
```

Este el codigo html que llama la url:

```
<div class="fondosaempleados">
    <div class="container submenutercer">
        <ul class="nav-justified">
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'empaqueingreso' %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ingresoempaque"> <span><img src='{% static "img/nuevarecepcion.png" %}' alt="" class="img-responsive" title=""></span>
                    <p>NUEVO INGRESO</p>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Este es el codigo de la ventana modal y el formulario:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrarmodal">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> </i>
    </button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Ingresar caja</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="formatolinea" method="post" action="{% url 'empaqueingreso' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Variedad</label>
            <select name="variedad">
                <option></option>
                <option>Freedom</option>
                <option>Vendela</option>
            </select>
            <label>Grado</label>
            <select name="grado">
                <option></option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="60">60</option>
                <option value="70">70</option>
            </select>
            <label>Tipo de empaque</label>
            <select name="empaque">
                <option></option>
                <option>Tabaco</option>
                <option>Full</option>
                <option>Cuarto</option>
                <option>Tercio</option>
                <option>Octavos</option>
            </select>
            <label>Cantidad de ramos</label>
            <input type="number" name="ramos">
            <label>Unidades por ramo</label>
            <select name="unidades">
                <option></option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>25</option>
                <option>Otro</option>
            </select>
            <label>Comercializadora</label>
            <select name="comercializadora">
                <option></option>
                <option>QU</option>
                <option>GO</option>
                <option>FX</option>
                <option>BG</option>
            </select>
            <label>Numero de celda</label>
            <input type="number" name="celda">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{mensaje}}</div>
            <br>
            <button class="guardar" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
            <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.containerfluid -->
</div>
```

Funcion JS:

```
function iempaque() {
    if (document.iempaque.mensaje.value == 'La celda ya esta ocupada') {
        alert("Debe seleccionar una nueva celda")
        document.iempaque.mensaje.focus()
        return false;
    }

    alert("La informacion se ha almacenado con exito");
    document.nclasificacion.submit();

}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no tiene que ver con Django, mira esta pregunta y entenderás: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516475/how-to-open-a-url-as-a-bootstrap-modal-window

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, Mira Lo Que quiero hacer es validar el formulario  antes de enviar la INFORMACIÓN ES Si La celda X ya esta Ocupada Y Si Es Así then me retorne a la ventana modal de nuevo con el error.

Comment: Los que tu llamas "ventanas modales" son adornos hechos con JavaScript y CSS, pero en realidad __no es una ventana__. Si quieres validar tu formulario antes de enviarlo, usa JavaScript y si quieres mostrar un diálogo modal (que no es una ventana) debes activarla desde la URL.

Comment: Creo que no me hago entender lo que pasa es que ya valida la información y lo que quiero hacer es que si ya existe la información me retorne al modal con los errores

Comment: Es que Django no crea los dialogos modales. Lo tienes que hacer con Bootstrap. Esta es la documentación http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage ... aunque la solución que buscas está en el enlace de mi primer comentario. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Si yo se que django no los crea lo que quiero es que envié la información y esta esta mal y me retorna el formulario pero quiero que esto lo haga dentro del modal.

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendacion, es usar lo que django te ofrece... para hacer lo que quieres hacer de una forma fácil... lo mejor es que crees un Formulario con tus campos y no los preguntes en el request.POST, ademas de ser una buena practica te ahorras ciertas validaciones... un ejemplo seria este en forms.py

```
from django import forms

class FormularioCrearEmpaque(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'has-error' # si trabajas con bootstrap
    class Meta:
        model = Empaque
        fields = ('variedad', 'empaque', 'grado', 'comercializadora', 'ramos', 'unidades', 'celdas')
```

en tu vista de views.py podrias llamarlo

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormularioCrearEmpaque(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): # Se encargara de hacerte saber si el formulario es valido o no...
        try:
            # te haria un cambio a get y no filter porque por lo que veo, un empaque tiene una celda única... en todo caso si quieres seguir usando filter, la recomendacion de django es usar el método '.exists()'
            Empaque.objects.get(celda=form.cleaned_data['celda'])
            # podrias hacerlo asi, pero tambien es buena idea usar 'Messages' de django
            mensaje = 'La celda ya esta ocupada'
            return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {'mensaje' : mensaje})
            # si usaras Messages de Django, quedaria asi:
            # messages.error(request, "La celda ya está ocupada")
            # return render(request, "inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {})
        except Empaque.DoesNotExist:
            empaque = form.save(commmit=False)
            empaque.fecha = fecha
            empaque.hora = hora
            empaque.save()
            return redirect('empaque')

    else: # cuando nó es valido... asegurate de devolver al template el formulario para que pueda ser cargado en tu modal con los errores
        error = True # es una variable opcional para ayudarte a saber cuando hay error
        return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {'error': error, 'form': form})
else:
    form = FormularioCrearEmpaque()
return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {'form': form})
```

ya luego de esto... solo falta tu template... en el cual, de hacerlo con este código, deberás cambiar el formulario, podrias poner simplemente un '{{ form.as_p }}' y agregar el boton sumbit...

IMPORTANTE... recuerdas la variable llamada 'error' que enviaste cuando el formulario estaba incorrecto... en tu template

ingresoe.html

```
...
// en algun lado en el javascript
{% if error%}
{% comment %}Aquí debe ir el codigo que haga click sobre el boton que llama a tu modal, de tal modo que cuando ocurra un error, el modal pueda ser mostrado gracias a este click{% endcomment %}
$('#ingresoempaque').click();
{% endif %}
...
```

creo que eso seria mas que suficiente, espero poder haberte ayudado con tu duda

Comment: Hola si es lo que necesito pero no entiendo muy bien lo del error me  lo podrías explicar.

Comment: Cada vez que envias un formulario al servidor, la pagina por defecto se recarga, entonces es cuando django empieza a validar tu formulario, en el caso de el formulario contenga errores, django te dice cuales campos tienen errores; la variable es opcional, se puede hacer de muchas formas, pero escogí esa para que supieras que nosotros sabemos que hay un error, y cuando recargue, la pagina, se dará cuenta de esa variable, y ejecutará lo que hay dentro de el if del template... haciendo que el modal se muestre, ya que este por defecto está oculto, otra forma es hacerlo con form.errors

Comment: No hay una forma en que no sea necesario el formulario django y pueda hacer uso de mi formulario html.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que si se activa el mensaje vuelva a aparecer la ventana modal con el formulario los datos y el mensaje de error, creo que es con javascript pero no se muy bien.

Comment: Puedes hacer la validacion completa con javascript, desde luego, incluso sin recargar la página, con los formularios de django es mejor, y son buenas practicas, ya que el valida los campos y te protege de ciertos ataques, ademas lo que quieres hacer ya lo hacen los formularios de django entonces es como reinventar lo ya inventado, porque con validacion desde el servidor debes buscar una forma de pasar los datos nuevamente al front con los campos con errores, y llenar el formulario... si tienes dudas de como usar los formularios de django, puedes contactarte conmigo y te podia explicar via mail